# Заполнение массива случайными значениями

Tags: php

Собственно задание. Создать 2 массива с именами полей val1, val2, val3. Заполнить случайными значения от 0 до 10 по 100 строк в каждом массиве.

```
$array1 = array('val1'=>rand(0,10),'val2'=>rand(0,10),'val3'=>rand(0,10));
$array2 = array('val1'=>rand(0,10),'val2'=>rand(0,10),'val3'=>rand(0,10));
```

Правильно, ли работает данный код?

Comment: а самому проверить?

Comment: не верен в правильности, поэтому и спрашиваю

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php       
   function makeRandArray(){
     $randArray = array();
     for($i =1; $i <= 100; $i++){
       $randArray['val' . $i] = rand(0, 10);
       }
     return $randArray;
   }

   $array1 = makeRandArray();
   $array2 = makeRandArray();
```

Comment: спасибо разобрался

Comment: подскажи ,как сделать так, чтобы была поверка на совпадение двух любых элементов в массивах, использую для этого функцию array_intersect_assoc но она,проверяет на существование всех элементов , как исправить?

Comment: in_array добавь

Comment: @korolariya элементы в массиве заполнены случайным образом ,поэтому данная штука не сработает

Comment: Не понимаю задачи тогда

Comment: Задача в следующем. Создать 2 массива с именами полей val1, val2, val3. Заполнить случайными значения от 0 до 10 по 100 строк в каждом массиве. (Эта часть выполнена выше)
Найти строки массивов у которых любые 2-поля совпадают с любыми двумя полями в другом массиве.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что нет. Вероятно правильно надо толковать так

> с именами полей val1, val2, val3, ..., val100

Comment: а как тогда генерировать массив с полями от val1, val2, val3, ..., val100 и которые имели бы случайные значения от 0 до 10

Comment: @ChromeChrome с помощью цикла от 1 до 100